# Is the Diophantine equation $y(x^3-y)=z^2+2$ solvable?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Do there exists integers $a,b$ such that their sum is a perfect cube while their product minus two is a perfect square?
>
> Equivalently, do there exist integers $x,y,z$ such that
> $$
> y(x^3-y)=z^2+2 \quad ? 
> $$

The source of this problem is the MathOveflow question ["What is the smallest unsolved diophantine equation?"](https://mathoverflow.net/q/316708) that introduces a way to measure size of a Diophantine equation and asks for a non-trivial equation of the smallest size. I was able to solve all equations of size up to 25, but cannot solve this equation of size 26.

**Update 21st July 2021**: Thank you Servaes for solving the above equation. I also received a solution by e-mail from Prof. Will Sawin. In the comment you ask what is the next smallest open equations. Now all equations with sizes up to 28 has been solved, so the smallest nontrivial ones are of size 29. Examples are
$$
y^2 - xyz + z^2 = x^3-5
$$
and
$$
y(x^2+2) = 2zx+2z^2+1.
$$
The last equation can of course be formulated as a question whether there exist integers $x$ and $z$ such that $x^2+2$ is a divisor of $2zx+2z^2+1$.

**Update 24th July 2021**: I now was able to solve $y(x^2+2) = 2zx+2z^2+1$, but not yet $y^2 - xyz + z^2 = x^3-5$.

**Update 16th August 2021**: Thank you Dipramit Majumdar and B. Sury for solving the equation $y^2 - xyz + z^2 = x^3-5$. Please look at my mathoverflow question
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400714/can-you-solve-the-listed-smallest-open-diophantine-equations
for the list of next smallest open equations.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: If I was taking a class which presented this problem, I would expect previous theorems, worked examples, or solved problems from the class or corresponding book used in the class to be pertinent.  I would regard these as tools to be used to attack the problem.  What is the source of this problem?

Comment: If the problem is not from a class, then you will need training to attack the problem on your own, so that you can show work in your question.  Showing work, and describing the problem's background will answer the requirements in [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), which is what the comment of @saulspatz is referring to.  For *on-the-fly* training, I suggest googling for "diophantine equations pdf".

Comment: I gotta admit, that motivation is 100x better than I would have guessed. Thanks so much for the rich context!

Comment: I look forward to the next smallest nontrivial Diophantine equation :)

Comment: The equations of the form $x^3+y^3+z^3=n$ are interesting because, while we know their solutions for all small $n$, for many values of $n$ finding them required a supercomputer. Geometrically, they are obtained from taking a smooth cubic surface in $\mathbb P^3$ and removing a smooth cubic curve at infinity. I suspect that there are more equations of that form which have solutions, but where finding the smallest solution would also require a supercomputer.

Comment: Your equations seem to be converging closer to that form - the newest one, if I calculated correctly, can be obtained from a smooth cubic surface in $\mathbb P^3$ by removing the cubic curve $x (x^2 +yz)$ with just two node singularities.  I don't know whether these two nodes allow for an approach better than brute force...

Comment: @Bogdan can you edit your post to make the latest unsolved equation an explicit question? Not to mention that it needs updating, assuming the preprint in the second answer below is what you want. People are downvoting that answer because you didn't ask for solutions or lack of to that troublesome equation.

Comment: I appreciate the new problems, but I think it is better to post them as new questions. Preferably after having made an attempt at finding a solution yourself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be integers such that $y(x^3-y)=z^2+2$. If $z$ is odd then
$$y(x^3-y)\equiv z^2+2\equiv3\pmod{8},$$
and so $y$ and $x^3-y$ are odd, meaning that $x$ is even. Then $x^3\equiv0\pmod{8}$ and so
$$y(x^3-y)\equiv-y^2\equiv7\pmod{8},$$
a contradiction. On the other hand, if $z$ is even then
$$y(x^3-y)\equiv z^2+2\equiv2\pmod{4},$$
and so either $y$ or $x^3-y$ is even, but not both. It follows that $x$ is odd. In the factorization
$$x^6-8=(x^2-2)(x^4+2x^2+4),$$
the gcd of the two factors on the right hand side divides $12$, but $x^2-2$ is odd and $x^2-2\not\equiv0\pmod{3}$ so in fact the two are coprime. We have
$$x^2-2\equiv3\pmod{4},$$
so $x^2-2$ has a prime factor $p\equiv3\pmod{4}$ with odd multiplicity that does not divide $x^4+2x+4$. It follows that $x^6-8$ has a prime factor $p\equiv3\pmod{4}$ with odd multiplicity. It is a classical result that then $x^6-8$ is not a sum of two squares. But this contradicts the identity
$$x^6-8=(2y-x^3)^2+(2z)^2.$$
So there is no pair of integers whose sum is a perfect cube and whose product is two more than a perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

The equation
$$y^2+z^2+5 = x^3 + xyz$$
has no integral solution.

The idea is following:
For an integer value of $x=k$ you get a Pell's equation and show that all these Pell's equations have no integral solution.

The proof is slightly long to write here. With Prof. B. Sury, we wrote down the solution. You can find it below.

[https://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/fruitdiopheqn1.pdf](https://www.isibang.ac.in/%7Esury/fruitdiopheqn1.pdf)

I look forward to your next equation.

arXiv link: https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.02640

Comment: Well I don't know why some people are downvoting for late answer, but I don't see a solution to this problem here (or anywhere else).

Comment: To begin with, the question you're trying to answer is not the OP's original one. There should be a separate question, and you could in fact post your own new and self-answered question. This said, and that's the second possible critic of your answer above, it would be preferable to typograph that new answer in MathJax format, and not post a link to an external document.

Comment: Just for your reference, the formulation as an equation involving fruit is due to me, here: https://thehighergeometer.wordpress.com/2021/07/27/diophantine-fruit/, and I got the equation directly from the edited version of the question here

Comment: @user3733558 the OP edited the question on the 24th July to include the specific equation shown insolvable here.

Comment: There is a typo in equation (4), it should read $u^2 - (k^2 -4)v^2 = k^3-5$, instead of $4k^3-5$. I thank Aubrey de Grey for pointing that out to me. I'll fix this in the arXiv version of the notes and add the relevant references.

Comment: Updated version is now available in Prof. Sury's webpage. [link](https://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/research.html)  New arXiv version will be available on Tuesday.